# How can I tell when all background threads in the current app have finished executing?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have some code that can spawn background worker threads from anywhere within it. This usually runs as a windows service.

I now need to run the same code from a win forms app (which will usually be run through visual studio rather than from a standalone exe).

When I run the main thread, it exits and returns control to the UI, however there may still be background threads running. Someone can then close the app/stop debugging and it terminates the other threads.

How can I prevent this (i realise i cant prevent it being terminated, i mean make the user aware so *they* dont terminate it) by making my app aware of all the child-threads that might have been spawned and wait for them to exit?

Is there a way to get the number of currently executing background threads and wait for this to be zero?

I'd rather not add code to the places where i spawn the new threads, because it isnt their concern.

Thanks

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: How do you create the background threads? Is it `new Thread()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you'll have to make a change to your threads and their launcher, one simple way I've used (if you're creating your own threads) is to increment a counter as you launch each thread and use a callback method in each thread that decrements the counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add support for cancellation:

1. Set the **WorkerSupportsCancellation** property to true.
2. Periodically check the **CancellationPending** property from within the **DoWork event handler**. If it’s true, set the event argument’s Cancel property to true, and return.
3. Call **CancelAsync** to request cancellation. (or when you exit your application)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [`Process.GetCurrentProcess.Threads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx).
But please be aware that you will always have at least one thread running - your main thread. So don't wait until the value will reach zero, because it never ever will while the program is running.

Additionally, I am not sure, this is going to work, because that property returns the operating system threads of the application which don't necessarily map to the managed threads, IIRC.

So, the right way would be to implement a tracking mechanism that let's you track your threads.

BTW: Simply declaring the threads as foreground threads will prevent your application from closing until the threads finished. However, it doesn't prevent your UI from closing.